# Let $A = (0,1]$. Then$\text{ inf}(A) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I posted before about this proposition and I thought I got it right but then I was told that it is still wrong so I am really confused again..

Here is my proof

Proof : Let $A = (0,1]$

Here, since $0 ≤ a$ for all $a ∈ A$, $0$ is an lower bound

Now, suppose that there is some $b ∈ R$ such that $b$ is a lower bound for $A$ and $b > 0$

Then assuming $b ≤ 1$, since $b ∈ A$, b can not be a lower bound of $A$.

Note that $$\frac b2 \in A \;\;\;and\;\;\;\frac b2<b=\text{inf}(A)$$which contradicts the property that $\text{inf}(A)$ is smaller than any element of $A$.

Hence $0$ is an $\text{inf}(A)$.

Please help!

Comment: This looks perfectly fine. You don't need to assume $b \le 1$; if $b > 1$ clearly it cannot be an inf for $A$ because then already $1 < b$ which already contradicts the definition of inf. What do you think is incorrect or questionable in your proof?

Comment: Seems good, but notice that the contradiction is that $b$ is not a lower bound thus no number greater than zero can be a lower bound and so the smallest lower bound must be zero.

Comment: I was not told that exactly which part is incorrect but I was thinking that  "Then assuming b≤1, since b∈A, b can not be a lower bound of A"  this part may not be clear.

Comment: Indeed it is not. You proof seems a little confused; the fact that $b \in A$ does not mean that it cannot be a lower bound for $A$. What confused you in the other post? I posted an answer, if you have trouble understanding it comment on it! :-) Doing a very similar question is not encouraged :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is good. Alternatively, for a direct proof, note $A$ is non-empty and bounded below. Every lower bound $c$ of $A$ must satisfy $c \notin \mathbb{R_+}$ since for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R_+}$ there is some $n$ such that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n} \in A$.  Since $\max \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R_+} = 0$, and $0$ is a lower bound of $A$, it follows $\inf A = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is fine. Just take some care with the assumption that "since $b \in A$, b can not be a lower bound of A".

For example:
$A = [0, 1]$. The infimum of this set is also $0$ and $0 \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that $$\frac b2<b\leq\text{inf}(A).$$ This being a contradiction implies that $b>\inf(A)$.